# Execute jquery code in sequencial way

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a simple code I want to execute in sequencial way with javascript.I want to ensure code after for loops executes only after loop ends, as its obvious from the code.How to make that happen.
Thanks a lot in advance.

```
 $('div #currentAppointment').append('<ul>');
       for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
           $('div #currentAppointment').append('<li><a onclick=openModal('+b+')>' + data[b].name + '-' + data[b].task + '</a></li>');
       }
 $('div #currentAppointment').append('</ul');
```

Comment: can you write what you want to do sequentially?In steps 1,2,3...

Comment: This is already in sequential way. What's happening instead?

Comment: That;s not how DOM/jQuery works. Each tag is an _element_. You can't insert the opening and closing tags separately.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking - can you clarify the question? Should data[b].name actually be data[a].name since a is the loop variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $ul = $('<ul>');

for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
  $ul.append('<li><a></a></li>');
}

$('div #currentAppointment').append($ul);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be

```
   var html= "";
   for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {            
       html+= '<li><a onclick=openModal('+b+')>' + data[b].name + '-' + data[b].task + '</a></li>';
   }
   $('div #currentAppointment').append('<ul>'+html+'</ul>');
```